# How to get difference between two dates in days in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

Following is a query in oracle.

`SELECT start_date - TO_DATE('1900-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM start_table`

In oracle it gives the output 44680.3646, where start_date is 01-MAY-22.
what query would require to form to get the same output in EDB and postgresql

Comment: An Oracle `date` is equivalent to a `timestamp` in Postgres because it does include a time part. A `date` in Postgres has no time, so the difference between to `date` values is always an integer representing the number of days - and it will never contain fractional days.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the fractional part of a day, then you need to convert each value to number of seconds [using](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-datetime) `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` and divide by 86400(number of seconds in 1 day) and then find the difference of the results.

```
SELECT extract(epoch from '2022-05-01 11:44:16'::timestamp - '1900-05-02'::timestamp) / 86400  as date
```

Result: `44559.489074074074`

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e4c1f80211576b89026628abd4b2878)